# Headphone automatically muted in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: alsa, headphones

I've a strange problem in my Ubuntu. Every time I plug a headphone my Speaker volume automatically gets mute and its gain goes to 0 dB as you can see in the figure below.

[image: alsamixer]

I cannot unmute the Speaker via system settings because it only controls the Master volume.

Yes, I can use alsamixer and unmute the speaker and I can use the following command to unmute it:

```
amixer set -c 1 Speaker 64 unmute
```

It works, but, I have to type this everytime I plug a headphone. So, I'm not happy with this solution.

It's likely ubuntu has a configuration file to define my sound card behaviour, but I don't know where it is and how to configure it. Someone could give me an orientation ?